# Effective Java By Joshua Bloch: Item1 - Static Factory Method

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory, effective-java

I am reading the `Effective Java` by Joshua Bloch and I have question about Item1 `Static Factory Method`.

**Quote[Bloch, p.7]**

> Interfaces cant have static methods,
>   so by convention, static factory
>   methods for an interface named Type
>   are put in non-instantiable class
>   named Types. For example, the Java
>   Collections Framework, provide
>   unmodifiable collections, synchronized
>   collections, and the like. Nearly all
>   of these implementations are export
>   via static factory methods in one
>   noninstantiable class
>   (java.util.Collections). The classes
>   of the returned objects are all
>   non-public.

Ok. When look at the sources code, I see `java.util.Collection` interface and `java.util.Collections` class with private constructor (non-instantiable class). and I see that the non-instantiable class Collections has all static methods, just like what Bloch said. But i fail to see the connection between the two classes as Bloch said

**Interfaces cant have static methods, so by convention, static factory methods for an interface named Type are put in non-instantiable class named Types.**

1. Can anyone point out the obvious to me?
2. what is it mean when he said

**The classes of the returned objects are all non-public**

Here is where I obtain the java sources: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collection.java?av=f

Comment: See also [Bloch, Item 1](http://drdobbs.com/java/208403883?pgno=1).

Comment: anything about Bloch is plus one for me, by default.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. **Interfaces cant have static methods, so by convention, static factory methods for an interface named Type are put in non-instantiable class named Types**.

   The point is just the **plural 's' on "Type[s]"**. So if your interface is called `Foo` and you want to create some implementation called `MyFoo` then your factory with the methods to instantiate should be called `Foos` by convention.
2. **The classes of the returned objects are all non-public**

   This means that the classes of objects returned from the factory methods have a private or default visibility modifier as in `private class MyFoo{}` so that they can not be instantiated by any other means but their factory methods. Since you can't construct an Object using the `new` operator from private inner or package private class out of their scope (reflection aside).

e.g.:

```
 public interface Foo{ //interface without plural 's' (question 1)
     public void bar();
 }
 public abstract class Foos(){ // abstract factory with plural 's' (question 1)
    public static Foo createFoo(){
        return new MyFoo();
    }
    private class MyFoo implements Foo{ // a non visible implementation (question 2)
       public void bar(){}
    }
 }
```

Comment: Great explanation on `1`. I understand it must better. Thank you very much. For `2`: what is the benefit of having the return object to be the instance of a private class?

Comment: you're able to switch implementations without an API user noticing, since he never constructed one of the objects himself using `new`. So if you need to reimplement something you can create a new release without any API changes

Comment: Hm, I find that I need to add 'static' modifier to the inner class MyFoo in order to get this to compile... Otherwise I get the error that no enclosing instance of Foos exist. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Mats_SX: I just read something on that. http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2012/02/why-non-static-variable-cannot-be.html What it basically boils down to is that in the inner MyFoo class, you have instantiate an instance of Foos and reference it.

Comment: One good example is the [`Lists`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html) class from Guava, which contains static factory functions for `List` instances. For instance, you can create a list of strings with the following code: `List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList("first", "second", "third")`

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have an interface called `List` and you want to use the static factory method to create different type of lists. You cannot define the static factory methods in the `List` interface because it's an interface. So what you have to do it have a class that return instances of classes that implement List

```
public class ListFactory{
  private ListFactory(){}
  public static List makeArrayList(){...}
  public static List makeLinkedList(){...}
  public static List makeCrazyList(){...}
}
```

You cannot do this

```
public interface List{
   public static List makeArrayList();
   public static List makeLinkedList();
   public static List makeCrazyList();
}
```

Since `List` is interface.

Comment: As of java 8, the restriction that interfaces cannot contain static method was eliminated.

Answer (score 2):

So take for example [Collections.unmodifiableList(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29). It returns some implementation of List. But the implementation class's name is irrelevant. Furthermore, said class is *only* constructed through the static factory method.

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface Foo
    static public class Factory
        public Foo create(){..}

Foo foo = Foo.Factory.create();
```

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't understand your question here. `Collection` is the interface and `Collections` has some factory methods like `emptyList`

2) E.g the List instance that is returned by `Collection.emptyList` is an instance of a private class that implements the `List` interface.

Comment: I have another question for you. For `2`, what is the benefit of having the return object to be the instance of a private class?

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that the return type of the static factory methods in `Collections` (and other classes like it) are interface types (e.g. `List`) rather than specific implementation classes (e.g. `java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableList`), which are not visible to users since that would just complicate things and increase the size of the API.