# static factory method in interface class java

Tags: java, static-factory

I was reading **Effective java** text book. First item is about using static factory methods instead of public constructor. My doubt is that if i am specifying an `Interface` how can i specify a static factory method in the `Interface` ? Because java does not support static methods inside `interface`. The text book specifies about creating a **non-instantiable class** containing the public static factory methods. But how can those method access the private constructor of the implementation class?

The text book says if you are defining an `Interface Type` , create a non-instantiable class `Types` and include the static factory methods in that class. But how can a method defined in the `Types` class access the private constructor of a concrete implementation of `Interface Type`

EDIT:- Below sentence is quoted from the text book. Please explain me its meaning

"Interfaces can’t have static methods, so by convention, static factory methods for an interface named *Type* are put in a noninstantiable class (Item 4) named *Types* "

EDIT:- taken from [Effective Java By Joshua Bloch: Item1 - Static Factory Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129026/effective-java-by-joshua-bloch-item1-static-factory-method)

```
     public interface Foo{ //interface without plural 's' (question 1)
     public void bar();
 }
 public abstract class Foos(){ // abstract factory with plural 's' (question 1)
    public static Foo createFoo(){
        return new MyFoo();
    }
    private class MyFoo implements Foo{ // a non visible implementation (question 2)
       public void bar(){}
    }
 }
```

My question is that how can the static method `createFoo()` calls the private constructor of `MyFoo`

Comment: This should help you understand:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129026/effective-java-by-joshua-bloch-item1-static-factory-method

Comment: it makes the concept more clear. But my doubt still stands. how can the static method createFoo() calls the private constructor of MyFoo

Comment: You miss quoted the text book. The actual paragraph was:

> Prior to Java 8, interfaces couldn’t have static methods. By convention, static
factory methods for an interface named Type were put in a noninstantiable companion class (Item 4) named Types .

Comment: @mLotfizad but which Types class is this referring to? I cannot find any factory method in java.sql.Types

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define the factory as returning the Interface but internally it creates a concrete class.

For example:

```
public Interface I { }

private class Impl implements I {
}

I buildI() {
    return new Impl();
}
```

The trick is to create the implementations with package private (or even if they are inner classes private) constructors and then only the factory can build them.

The power of this method is that the factory can build the appropriate implementation depending on the requirements and that all happens invisibly to the user. For example when you create an `EnumSet` using the factory there are multiple internal implementations depending on how many entries there are in the `Enum` that the `EnumSet` is being built for. A super-fast version using bitfields on a long for `Enums` with less than 64 entries, a slower version for longer enumerations.

To specify the interface for a factory all you need to do is:

```
public interface Factory {
   I buildI();
}
```

Now people can call you with `setFactory(new FactoryImpl());` you can then call `factory.buildI()` and their code then returns the concrete implementation.

You can take this a step further and use Generics:

```
public interface GenericFactory<T> {
    T buildInstance();
}
```

And then your `setFactory` becomes:

```
public void setFactory(GenericFactory<I> factory);
```

To create a factory they do:

```
public class FactoryImpl implements GenericFactory<I> {
     @override
     I buildInstance() {
        return new impl();
     }
}
```

But now you can use that same factory class for absolutely anything that needs a factory, just change the generics requirement.

The reason it can call the private constructor is very simple - it's declared in the same class!

Inside one Java file you can create the class with the private constructor. You then define the static method inside the class and even though it is static it still has the privileges required to access the constructor.

If the factory and implementation are in separate classes then they will be placed in the same package and the method made package private instead of private.

Comment: i want to force the implementer to add the static factory method with a pre-defined name which is specified in the Interface.

Comment: buidI() method should be static so that user can call that method without using the factory object

Comment: Your requirement doesn't make any sense then. It's also impossible as an interface can't require a static method.

Comment: so what does that sentence i quoted in the EDIT means?

Comment: You can create a class with a static factory method. What you cannot do is create an Interface that forces a class implementing it to create a static method.

Comment: I can always add a static method in the implementation class. That's not my doubt. Can you please check my last edit? There the static method and the implementation are two different classes.

Comment: I added a couple more paragraphs to my answer.

Comment: So i guess i have to make my constructors Package private instead of private right?

Comment: Yes, it sounds that way :)

Answer (score 5):

Java 8 finally allows interfaces to have static methods.

See [this archived copy of the TechEmpower blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20181120154915/http://www.techempower.com/blog/2013/03/26/everything-about-java-8/) for details.

Comment: Not really. How exactly is it solved? Besides your answer being a link-only answer, the link you reference says nothing about static factory methods.

Answer (score 4):

One way to think about this is with the package encapsulation in mind. Consider this Java 9+ code:

```
public interface Engine {

    void start();

    static Engine getEngine(String type) {
        switch (type) {
            case "combustion":
                return new CombustionEngine();
            case "electric":
                return new ElectricEngine();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown engine type : " + type);
        }
    }
}

class CombustionEngine implements Engine {

    CombustionEngine() {
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        // injecting fuel and igniting it to create combustion...
    }
}

class ElectricEngine implements Engine {

    ElectricEngine() {
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        // electric current from battery flowing through coil in magnetic field...
    }
}
```

Note that constructors in implementations are package-private so the caller from a different package can't instantiate implementation directly and should use the factory method.

Having the factory method in the interface

- has no need for a dedicated `EngineFactory` class (the traditional implementation of Factory method design pattern)
- reminds to **Program to interface, not implementation**

If needed, there is also a way to create implementation instances as singletons, which improves memory footprint :

```
public interface Engine {

    enum EngineType {

        COMBUSTION,
        ELECTRIC;

        private static EnumMap<EngineType, Engine> MAP = new EnumMap<>(EngineType.class);

        static {
            MAP.put(COMBUSTION, new CombustionEngine());
            MAP.put(ELECTRIC, new ElectricEngine());
        }
    }

    void start();

    static Engine getEngine(EngineType type) {
        return EngineType.MAP.get(type);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It talks about creating object via static factory method in the implementation not the interface

```
public Interface MyInterface {
    public void myFunction();
}

public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    // constructor is made private
    private MyClass() {}

    // Use this to create object instead use static factory
    public static MyClass getInstance() {
        return new MyClass();
    }

    public void myFunction(){
      // your implementation
    } 
}
```

A previous post also talks about static factory method.. [What are static factory methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods-in-java)

Apart from the book I also find the undermentioned link a good read
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/static-factory-methods-vs-traditional-constructors.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a factory method in an interface, but you cannot have a constructor in an interface either: Interfaces cannot be instantiated. The point is to use a factory method instead of a constructor in the classes implementing the interface, not in the interface itself.