# Best way to instantiate a fragment?

Tags: java, android, fragment

***Method 1***

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int index) {

    MyFragment f = new MyFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle(1);

    args.putInt("index", index);

    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;

  }
```

Usge

```
Myfragment.newInstance(1);
```

***Method 2***

```
 public MyFragment newInstance(int index) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle(1);

    args.putInt("index", index);

    setArguments(args);

    return this;
  }
```

Usge

```
new Myfragment().newInstance(1);
```

In the above snippets which one is more appropriate and preferable way and please point out why ?

And now am doing this..

```
 List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
            fragments.add(new MyFragment().newInstance(defaultId));
            int i = 1;
            for (Categories categories : mCategories) {
                String id = categories.getCategory_id();
                String name = categories.getCategory_name();
//                String slno = categories.getSlno();
                fragments.add(new MyFragment().newInstance(defaultId));
                Titles[i] = name;
                i++;
            }
```

Anything wrong with this ?

Comment: the first is a static factory method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead with `Method 1`. Always try to use `Static Factory Methods` over `Constructors`. Why you need to use this could be found out in the famous book `Effective Java` By Joshua Bloch: Item1 - Static Factory Method.

Also you could refer: [Effective Java By Joshua Bloch: Item1 - Static Factory Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129026/effective-java-by-joshua-bloch-item1-static-factory-method)

Comment: I'm looping the fragments and adding to `List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();` if it static the memory wont get freed when destroy the activity know ?

Comment: This is a static method to create the Fragment object. That's all. So there is no way this will cause any memory problem. The Fragment object will not have reference inside this method. Kindly read 'Item 1' on Effective Java.

Comment: If i use static method might be use static variables too..wat about that ?
 `private static final String ARG_PAGE_ONE = "arg1";
    private static final String ARG_PAGE_TWO = "arg2";
    private static final String ARG_PAGE_THREE = "arg3";
    public static HomeScreenTabs create(String categoryId, String categoryName, String userId, boolean isGuest) {                                   
        HomeScreenTabs ob=new HomeScreenTabs();  Bundle bdl = new Bundle(4); bdl.putString(ARG_PAGE_ONE, categoryId); 
        bdl.setArguments(bdl);
        return ob;
    }`

Comment: So at every refresh the memory of those variables won't disallocate right ?

Comment: There will be a huge number of static variable stay alive even after on activity distroy at every refresh of page..

Comment: No. Only static methods, not static variable. `newInstance()` is not just a static method. It's a `static factory method`.

Answer (score 2):

Method 1 would be preferred over Method 2.

That's because in Method 1 you really create a `MyFragment` object. In Method 2 you first create a `MyFragment` object and then you initialize it with `newInstance(...)`. If you want to use method 2 i'd suggest to do it in 2 lines:

```
MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
frag.initialize(1);
```

with the initialize method:

```
public void initialize(int index) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle(1);
    args.putInt("index", index);
    setArguments(args);
}
```

Comment: Plz tell me..Wat's the wrong with the code in method 2 i had written in my qustion.??

Comment: well it's easy: you already create a new instance with `new MyFragment()`. After that you use a method called `newInstance()`. which implies that it creates (another) new instance which it doesn't! It's not wrong what you do there but it's neither nice nor the common way to do it!